# Compiling Error? (C++)

Tags: c++

I'm very new with C++, and I just wrote this code that asks you for input, and it becomes the variable, goes through a calculation, and gives an output. I get compiling errors that say 'int ns' and 'int sum' are not valid.

```
#include <iostream>

    int main () {

        sum = ns - 2 * 180;

        std::cout << "Enter the number of sides";

        int ns;
        int sum;

        std::cin >> ns;

        sum = ns * 180 - 360;

        std::cout << "The sum of all of the interior angles is" << sum;
        system("PAUSE");
    }
```

Could anyone tell me with's wrong here?

Comment: You're using an undefined types in `sum = ns - 2 * 180;` you need to move the declarations higher so move `int ns and int sum` above that line

Comment: Where do you declare `ns` and `sum`? Where do you use them first?

Comment: Also you use `std::cin >> ns;` but then try an operation on it on your first line which makes no sense

Answer (score 1):

Before using an identifier you have to define it. The compiler does not know what identifiers sum and ns mean in this code snippet

```
int main () {

    sum = ns - 2 * 180;
```

Moreover ns was not even initialized.

It seems that you should simply remove these two statements

```
   sum = ns - 2 * 180;

   std::cout << "Enter the number of sides";
```

The program will look something like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

int main () {

    int ns;
    int sum;

    std::cin >> ns;

    sum = ns * 180 - 360;

    std::cout << "The sum of all of the interior angles is " << sum << std::endl;
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use `sum` and `ns` before defining them.

define `ns` and `sum` and then use them.

For example:

```
int ns;
int sum;

//take input etc.
sum = ns - 2 * 180;
..............
```

Comment: @EdChum: Thanks ! I have made the changes.